# Creating a new float environment without the numbering but still displaying the float type

Tags: floats, counters

So I would like to create a new float environment using the float package (for example) but without a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{afloat}{t!}{log}
\floatname{afloat}{Algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{afloat}
\caption{getRandomNumber()}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State\Return 7 \Comment{Chosen by fair dice roll. Guaranteed to be random.}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{afloat}

\end{document}
```

yielding:

[image]

Now using `\caption*{}` removes the entire title (which could be replaced in each environment but that seems hacky).

So ideally the solution would look like above but without "1":

"**Algorithm** GetRandomNumber()".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to define an unnumbered label format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{afloat}{t!}{log}

\newcommand\afloatname{Algorithm}
\floatname{afloat}{\afloatname}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{unnumbered}{#1}
\captionsetup[afloat]{labelformat=unnumbered}

\begin{document}

\begin{afloat}
\caption{getRandomNumber()}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State\Return 7 \Comment{Chosen by fair dice roll. Guaranteed to be random.}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{afloat}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `\afloatname` in `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{unnumbered}{\afloatname}`? `#1` instead of `\afloatname` should work. Then the label format `unnumbered` can also be used for other float types.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek A remmanant from some tests I was doing. It's been corrected now. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

## Package `float` without package `caption`

Package defines the macro `\fnum@<float>`, which sets the float name and its number. It can be redefined to contain the name only.

The numbers in the list of algorithms can be removed by temporarily disabling `\numberline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{afloat}{t!}{loa}% The extension `.log` is already used by TeX!
\floatname{afloat}{Algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\fnum@afloat}{\fname@afloat}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begingroup
  \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{}
  \listof{afloat}{List of Algorithms}
\endgroup

\begin{afloat}
\caption{GetRandomNumber()}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State\Return 7 \Comment{Chosen by fair dice roll. Guaranteed to be random.}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{afloat}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]